# Gantt View Group by on 2 columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, gantt-view

I have simple calendar events which contain 2 user fields which have a start and end time spanning many calendar days.

the fields are user 1 and user 2.
based on this, is it possible to display a GANTT chart, grouped by the user showing any overlap of the user's calendar days?